# Clustering text documents using doc2vec

Tags: nlp, gensim

I am new to word/paragraph embedding and I am still trying to understand it. My question may be trivial. So please bear with me.

I have a collection of short documents (each documents contain few sentences and lots of noise). I want to cluster these documents according to the most similar documents into one cluster (soft cluster is fine for now). Now there are several techniques available (and noted tutorials such as in scikit-learn) but I would like to see if I can successfully use doc2vec (gensim implementation).

To this extent, I have ran the doc2vec on the collection and I have the "paragraph vector"s for each document. Obviously, I can cluster these vectors using something like K-Means. I am just wondering if this is the right approach or there is something else is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. Just try to keep the dimensionality of the embeddings low. See also https://github.com/facebookresearch/SentEval